Alignment issue in formfield
After adding a suffix icon, the alignment of the hint text changes, which affects the overall layout of the form. I tried to resolve this issue by adding content padding to the input field. However, this adjustment caused the validator text to shift to the right, disrupting the intended alignment.

  getPasswordWidget() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
      child: TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        obscureText: !mIsPasswordVisiblity,
        controller: passwordController,
        focusNode: _passwordFocus,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        /*  onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,*/

        /*  onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
          _fieldFocusChange(context, _loginIdFocus, _passwordFocus);
        },*/
        // controller: userNameController,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14,
            fontFamily: 'NotoSansRegular',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Color(0xFF333333)),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 52, top: 12),
          hintText: 'Password',
          labelStyle: TextStyle(),
          /*suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              _isPasswordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),*/
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400)),
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey.shade500),
          // border: InputBorder.none,
          alignLabelWithHint: true,

          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              mIsPasswordVisiblity ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              BlocProvider.of<LoginCubit>(blocContext).getPasswordVisibility();
              /*
              BlocProvider.of<ForgotPasswordCubit>(
                  blocContextForGotPassword)
                  .getPasswordVisibility();*/
              //  setState(() {
              //     _isPasswordVisible = !_isPasswordVisible;

              // });
            },
          ),
          //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        ),
        validator: (String? arg) {
          if (arg!.trim().isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter your Password';
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

Is there an alternative solution that ensures both the hint text and validator text remain properly aligned without negatively impacting the layout? I'm looking for a solution that maintains a consistent and visually appealing design across different screen sizes and devices, ensuring that all elements are correctly aligned and displayed as intended.

Please share image that you have tried so far.

Image added please refer

Also share reference image that you want to create.

Password Validator text needs to be aligned to left as "Please enter your User ID"
please refer the image

Actually, some in-built flutter icons have default padding. So can you please try to use a svg in the suffix icon, and please let me know if the issue persists? You can also try to give background color to the icon and text to learn more about the alignment issue.

ok will check that, Thanks for quick response, but still i want it in suffix icon not in svg, its a requirement

It is due to the default padding and alignment settings of TextFormField and InputDecoration. Try to use isDense: true and
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 52, 12)

Thanks for your response, after adding content padding, hint text alignment is also changed,

I have added code for this, hope it helps.

its not working,

Refer image that is generated with below code : https://imgur.com/IWEXaDf

Try below code...
 Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
            child: TextFormField(
              maxLines: 1,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              obscureText: true,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                fontFamily: 'NotoSansRegular',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Color(0xFF333333),
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 52, 12), // Adjust padding for suffix icon
                hintText: 'Password',
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                ),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                   Icons.visibility,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                   // BlocProvider.of<LoginCubit>(blocContext).getPasswordVisibility();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              validator: (String? value) {
                if (value!.trim().isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter your Password';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          )

